# array references in C

Tags: c

Hey all, the program below is supposed to take a .txt file, and count the number of words in it (assuming 's are letters of the word).  It should consider a word over when it encounters a space character.  Problem is when it prints out the array indexes, it should them all as maxed out integers, and not the number of words of that length.  Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(argc, argv)
  int argc;
  char *argv[];
{
  FILE *inFile;
  char ch;
  char ch1;
  int letterCount = 0;
  int i;

  int wordCount[20];


  void extern exit(int);
  if(argc > 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: fread <filename>\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  inFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  ch = fgetc(inFile);

  while (ch != EOF) {
    if ((isalpha(ch)) || (ch == '\''))
      letterCount++;
    else if ((ch == ' ') && (isalpha(ch1))) {
      wordCount[letterCount - 1] = wordCount[letterCount - 1] + 1;
      letterCount = 0;
    }

    ch1 = ch;
    ch = fgetc(inFile);
  }

  fclose;

  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    printf("Found %d words of length %d\n", wordCount[i], (i + 1));
}
```

Comment: `fclose` is a method, so should be `fclose(infile);`

Comment: actually, fclose is a function -- there are no methods in C.

Comment: @CharlieMartin - Technically yes, C has no language support for methods or objects. But if a "method" is a function that manipulates the "object" it's called on, fclose (and mose FILE * functions) satisfy that definition.

Comment: And if an amphibian is an animal that sometimes is in the water, then an otter is an amphibian.

Answer (score 4):

You never actually initialize the individual ints in wordCount to zero.

Comment: thanks man, sure enough that fixed it.  im coming from java so im not used to looking for that. thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

Umm, just add all of the lengths? This approach will fail if you get a word with a length greater than 20 BTW.

It seems that a better approach would be to just add a counter when you find a new word.

EDIT: After re-reading your post, it's not clear to me if you want the total number of words or the total number of words per length.

Answer (score 0):

You're not initializing the values in wordCount, and letterCount grows by 1 for every letter, which means the index in wordcount will be wrong.

Consider backing up and thinking about this one again.

Here are some hints:

```
int wc = 0;
int inword = 0; 
while((ch = fgetc(inFile) != EOF){
   if(/* not in word and hit a word character */){
      inword = 1;
   } else if ( /*in a word and hit a word separator */){
      wc += 1;
      inword = 0;
   } /* what else do you need here? */
}

/* output the word count */
```

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of doing somebody's homework, unless I had to do otherwise, I think I'd do something like this:

```
char word[21];
int letterCount = 0;
int wordCount[20] = {0};

while (1==fscanf(inFile, "%20s", word)) {
   size_t len = strlen(word);
   letterCount += len;
   ++wordCount[len];
}
```

Edit: I should add that as it stands, this doesn't *precisely* meet the specification as stated. OTOH, it's probably closer to what you really want (e.g., consider how your code treats tabs and new-lines).